# Azure portal allow deployment only through ARM templates or Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

I have been looking everywhere but I cannot find a solution to this problem.

In azure I have a `production`subscription, to which I would like to deny any sort of manual deployments and allow only deployment with arm templates OR terraform.

using azure group management policies, I did put in place the definition of blocking all sort of deployment `not allowed`. But this not only denies the deployment from the portal, but it does block the deployment with arms or terraform.

Can anyone help to understand how can I allow deployment as code, and block all the portal deployment?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide and if my question is not clear, please feel free to ask more info

Comment: Don't give users *Contributor* permissions and do all deployments through service principals.

Comment: Sorry what you mean to do all the deployment through service principle? To do this, do I need to set any particolar permission on the user?

Comment: Start by looking up what a service principal is and how they are used. That will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Daniel Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781754/daniel-mann). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

As Daniel suggested, "Don't give users `Contributor` permissions and do all deployments through **service principals**."

You can add a role assignment to an existing service principal using ARM templates.

**[Subscription deployments with ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli#access-control)**

For example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.4.1.14562",
      "templateHash": "17666923867108240565"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "rgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the resourceGroup to create"
      }
    },
    "rgLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for the resourceGroup"
      }
    },
    "principalId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "principalId of the user that will be given contributor access to the resourceGroup"
      }
    },
    "roleDefinitionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "roleDefinition to apply to the resourceGroup - default is contributor"
      }
    },
    "roleAssignmentName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[guid(parameters('principalId'), parameters('roleDefinitionId'), parameters('rgName'))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique name for the roleAssignment in the format of a guid"
      }
    }
  },
  "functions": [],
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
      "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "Note": "subscription level deployment"
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
      "name": "applyLock",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "inner"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {
          "principalId": {
            "value": "[parameters('principalId')]"
          },
          "roleDefinitionId": {
            "value": "[parameters('roleDefinitionId')]"
          },
          "roleAssignmentName": {
            "value": "[parameters('roleAssignmentName')]"
          }
        },
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "metadata": {
            "_generator": {
              "name": "bicep",
              "version": "0.4.1.14562",
              "templateHash": "12740078983609655962"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "principalId": {
              "type": "string",
              "metadata": {
                "description": "principalId of the user that will be given contributor access to the resourceGroup"
              }
            },
            "roleDefinitionId": {
              "type": "string",
              "metadata": {
                "description": "roleDefinition to apply to the resourceGroup - default is contributor"
              }
            },
            "roleAssignmentName": {
              "type": "string",
              "metadata": {
                "description": "Unique name for the roleAssignment in the format of a guid"
              }
            }
          },
          "functions": [],
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
              "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
              "name": "DontDelete",
              "properties": {
                "level": "CanNotDelete",
                "notes": "Prevent deletion of the resourceGroup"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
              "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
              "name": "[guid(parameters('roleAssignmentName'))]",
              "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', parameters('roleDefinitionId'))]",
                "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', parameters('rgName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can refer to [Is there a way to use ARM Template to create an Azure Service Principal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565067/is-there-a-way-to-use-arm-template-to-create-an-azure-service-principal), [Assign Azure roles using Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template), and [Automatic Service Principal creation in the Azure deployment](https://github.com/informatics-lab/aml-jupyterhub/issues/43)